# Windows 8 Pro, Windows 7 Pro downgrade rights and Windows 10 upgrade rights

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-10-upgrade

I have two genuine Windows 8 Professional product keys (one 32-bit, one 64-bit, though I think they work equally). Non-OEM.

I assume these have downgrade rights to Windows 7 (?)
Is that indicated to expire? 
If I install Windows 8 Pro (with said key) on a pc, then use upgrade rights to Windows 10, will I then have downgrade rights from 10 to 7 on that PC?

If so, what will happen to the 8 Pro product key, will it be void? Is downgrade rights to Windows 7 now locked into that computer?

Basically, I have no interest in Windows 8/8.1. So I would like to lock in a Windows 10 license, but perhaps not if I loose the (Windows 7) downgrade rights for the product key I need to use..

Answer (score -1):

before I have  windows 10 my keyboard was working properly after some message come up on my screen saying that is time to upgrade windows 10 all the characters wen wrong they all mix and I didn't ask  I rather prefer window 7 or 8.0  than windows 10

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. If you have a new question please [ask your own question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps).