# Windows 10 Downgrade rights/ OEM eligibility of Microsoft Refurbisher License/ COA & Installation/ Activation of Windows 8.1/ 8, 7 on such machines?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8.1, license, downgrade

Windows 10 Downgrade rights/ OEM eligibility of Microsoft Refurbisher License/ COA & Installation/ Activation of Windows 8.1/ 8, 7 on such machines?

Found a Registered/ Authorized Refurbisher (checked their name on MS website) selling a product with the following OS license.

> Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit Preloaded with new Microsoft Refurbisher License/COA and Recovery partition/ Recovery Media/ DVD

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/refurbishedpcs/buygenuine

[image]

PS: Based on this image from here, I think it's OEM legitimate and has the same allowances.

There is lot of information and discussion on Refurbished licenses (research links posted) and Downgrade rights, individually. But, I don't see a clear view on whether these Refurbished Licenses are equivalent to OEM and also include downgrade rights?

[Windows 8 Pro, Windows 7 Pro downgrade rights and Windows 10 upgrade rights](https://superuser.com/questions/1088399/windows-8-pro-windows-7-pro-downgrade-rights-and-windows-10-upgrade-rights)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mssmallbiz/2011/10/05/looking-to-provide-refurbished-pcs-what-you-need-to-know-about-the-microsoft-refurbisher-program

http://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/downgrade_rights.aspx

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/466519-microsoft-refurbisher-program

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/124055-downgrade-rights-for-windows-10-licensing-how-to

Does the Refurbished License/ COA qualify as OEM and hence have the same eligibility for Downgrade Rights?

If so, then which ISO/ Media would one need (from original OEM or Refurbisher??), how would one get the  License Key/ Product Key (from Refurbisher or OEM or MS?) and install and activate such a downgrade OS on such a machine under this program?

Comment: Ask MS support. Licensing questions are offtopic here.

Comment: Ok. I first searched and found the linked question and only because that existed did I bother with asking here. Please don't give negatives by closing or shutting this down. Not sure if SE has a points neutral way of closing something

Comment: I haven't done anything. But how should we answer this? you would only get speculations as answers but no facts.

Comment: Not saying you did but that's what typically happens. And I only asked after due searching and finding Such a question existed and was allowed here (linked) and maybe that policy has changed

Comment: @magicandre1981 what a licence says you can and cannot do is on topic here and indeed we have many questions that ask what upgrade/downgrade rights a licence gives you. What we cannot answer is whether any part of a licence is legally enforceable since that would require a lawyer and intimate knowledge of OPs judicial system. It is a subtle line to walk, but since licences should be freely available we can at least give a definitive indication of what the company issuing the licence will allow. We don't do legal advice, but we can say "in paragraph X of your licence...."

Comment: "Does the Refurbished License/ COA qualify as OEM and hence have the same eligibility for Downgrade Rights?" - You will have to contact Microsoft to determine the answer to this question because ultimately ONLY Microsoft will either recognize the license has the rights or not.  Yes; I am voting to closing.  Your welcome to ask your pratical question that you actually have though.

Comment: @Mokubai that is what I am asking. We know what OEM, Retail licenses allow us to do in terms of installing & how / upgrade/ downgrade. Need to know the same for Refurb License. My guess is they are equivalent to OEM channel